# How do I log correctly inside my Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby

Currently I'm using `puts`, but I'm sure that's not the correct answer.  How do I correctly setup a logger, inside my gem, to output my internal logging instead of `puts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little example:

```
gem 'log4r'
require 'log4r' 

class MyClass
  def initialize(name)

    @log = Log4r::Logger.new(name)
    #Add outputter
    #~ log.outputters << Log4r::FileOutputter.new('log_file', :filename => 'mini_example.log', :level => Log4r::ALL )
    log.outputters << Log4r::StdoutOutputter.new('log_stdout') #, :level => Log4r::WARN )
    #~ log.outputters << Log4r::StderrOutputter.new('log_stderr', :level => Log4r::ERROR)

    @log.level = Log4r::INFO
    @log.info("Creation")
    #~ @log.level = Log4r::OFF
  end
  attr_reader :log
  def myfunction(*par)
    @log.debug("myfunction is called")
    @log.warn("myfunction: No parameter") if par.empty?
  end
end  

x = MyClass.new('x')
x.myfunction

y = MyClass.new('y')
y.myfunction
y.myfunction(:a)
y.log.level = Log4r::DEBUG
y.myfunction(:a)
```

During initialization you create a Logger (`@log`). In your methods you call the logger.

With `@log.level=` (or `MyClass#log.level=`) you can influence, which messages are used.

You can use different outputters (in my example I log to STDOUT). You can also mix outputters (e.g. STDOUT with warnings, each data (including DEBUG) to a file...)

Answer (score 21):

You can keep the logger in your top-level module. Allow user's to set their own logger but provide a reasonable default for those who don't care to deal with logging. For e.g.

```
module MyGem
  class << self
    attr_writer :logger

    def logger
      @logger ||= Logger.new($stdout).tap do |log|
        log.progname = self.name
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then, anywhere within your gem code you can access the logger. For e.g.

```
class MyGem::SomeClass

  def some_method
    # ...
    MyGem.logger.info 'some info'
  end

end
```

References:

- [Using the Ruby Logger](https://www.hawkins.io/article/using-the-ruby-logger/)
- [Logger](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html)

Answer (score 19):

The most flexible approach for users of your gem is to let them provide a logger rather than setting it up inside the gem. At its simplest this could be

```
class MyGem
  class << self
    attr_accessor :logger
  end
end
```

You then use `MyGem.logger.info "hello"` to log messages from your gem (you might want to wrap it in a utility method that tests whether a logger is set at all)

Users of your gem can then control where messages get logged to (a file, syslog, stdout, etc...)

Comment: Please see my update, my wording was confusing.  I want to log inside my internal methods correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after then.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was about to make a horrible mistake.

Answer (score -7):

I think the easiest approach is to use it this way

```
Rails.logger.info "hello"
```

Comment: Why do you assume that Rails is used? The question talks only about Ruby and an own gem.

Comment: Was inattentive. In my case with Rails it's just helped, so sorry for offtop.