# How to write log inside my rubygem that will be used in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I'm developing a rubygem that will be used in a rails app. In this rubygem i need to log some information (warnings, errors...).

I saw some gems to do this, like [logging](https://github.com/TwP/logging), but apparently i need no configure the log output (stdout, some file).
My rails app log the messages in a file. So, my question: Is there a way to my gem use the same log configuration that my rails app uses? or my gem will send the log according to his own configuration?

Comment: You can check in your gem if Rails logger is defined and if so, use that, else you can fallback to STDOUT or some other implementation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may use `Rails.logger` directly, which is valid if your gem will always only be used within a Rails application. You may alternatively define a logger for your gem namespace and default to `Rails.logger` if defined, or `Logger.new(STDOUT)` if it's not, along with a writer, so it's overridable:

```rb
module MyGem
  def self.logger
    @@logger ||= defined?(Rails) ? Rails.logger : Logger.new(STDOUT)
  end

  def self.logger=(logger)
    @@logger = logger
  end
end
```

Whatever the case, you will use it like this:

```rb
MyGem.logger.debug "it works"
```

Comment: I have always used Rails.logger for this. This seems like the easiest/most straightforward approach.

Comment: This answer helped me incredibly! I just wanted to add something I ran into. I have a `test_helper.rb` with the statement `Minitest::Reporters.use!`, which, to my surprise, loads Rails and therefore `MyGem.logger` was raising an error. I fixed it changing `defined?(Rails)` for `defined?(Rails.logger)` and now it works perfectly!

Comment: I have upvoted this answer, but there's a better way here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31626738/1996540